# Splitting a word with dots between each char

Tags: c#

I have a word, for example:

```
qwerty
```

I want to add a dot between each char, but also take into consideration all possible cases.

For example, output should be:

```
qwerty
qwert.y
qwer.ty
qwer.t.y
qwe.rty
qwe.rt.y
qwe.r.ty
qwe.r.t.y
qw.erty
qw.ert.y
qw.er.ty
qw.er.t.y
qw.e.rty
qw.e.rt.y
qw.e.r.ty
qw.e.r.t.y
q.werty
q.wert.y
q.wer.ty
q.wer.t.y
q.we.rty
q.we.rt.y
q.we.r.ty
q.we.r.t.y
q.w.erty
q.w.ert.y
q.w.er.ty
q.w.er.t.y
q.w.e.rty
q.w.e.rt.y
q.w.e.r.ty
q.w.e.r.t.y
```

I have so far this code:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int maxPossibilities = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2.0, txtInput.Text.Length));
    List<string> allPossibilities = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxPossibilities; i++)
    {
        string result = "";
        string added = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(txtInput.Text.Length - 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < txtInput.Text.Length; j++)
        {
            result += txtInput.Text[j] + ((j < txtInput.Text.Length - 1) && (added[j].Equals('1')) ? "." : "");

        }
        allPossibilities.Add(result);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
qwerty
qwert.y
qwer.ty
qwer.t.y
qwe.rty
qwe.rt.y
qwe.r.ty
qwe.r.t.y
qw.erty
qw.ert.y
qw.er.ty
qw.er.t.y
qw.e.rty
qw.e.rt.y
qw.e.r.ty
qw.e.r.t.y
q.werty
q.wert.y
q.wer.ty
q.wer.t.y
q.we.rty
q.we.rt.y
q.we.r.ty
q.we.r.t.y
q.w.erty
q.w.ert.y
q.w.er.ty
q.w.er.t.y
q.w.e.rty
q.w.e.rt.y
q.w.e.r.ty
q.w.e.r.t.y
q.werty
q.werty
q.wert.y
q.wert.y
q.wer.ty
q.wer.ty
q.wer.t.y
q.wer.t.y
q.we.rty
q.we.rty
q.we.rt.y
q.we.rt.y
q.we.r.ty
q.we.r.ty
q.we.r.t.y
q.we.r.t.y
q.w.erty
q.w.erty
q.w.ert.y
q.w.ert.y
q.w.er.ty
q.w.er.ty
q.w.er.t.y
q.w.er.t.y
q.w.e.rty
q.w.e.rty
q.w.e.rt.y
q.w.e.rt.y
q.w.e.r.ty
q.w.e.r.ty
q.w.e.r.t.y
q.w.e.r.t.y
```

There are some duplicates in the output, but shouldn't be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maximum possibilities should be `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2.0, txtInput.Text.Length-1))`?

Comment: @user6274399 The expected o/p possibilities count is `32` whereas your `maxPossibilities` count you are acquiring is `64` have you checked that??

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik Oh, now I feel a bit stupid. I actually had `Length - 1` but I did some revisions and forgot to re-add it probably. Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.

Comment: @user6274399 did you not answer your own question then?

Comment: @AlexW Not really, Dheeraj Patnaik did. I appreciate his help.

Comment: yes sorry credit goes to Dheeraj Patnaik, well actually Hari Prasad as he pointed it out first. You should probably let people know the question is answered before they attempt to answer it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slight variation on your algorithm that looks at the bits of `i` to determine which positions should get dots:

```
    string input = "qwerty";
    int maxPossibilities = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2.0, input.Length));
    List<string> allPossibilities = new List<string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < maxPossibilities; ++i) 
    {
        string result = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
        {
            result += input[j];
            if((i & (1 << j)) != 0) { result += "."; }
        }

        allPossibilities.Add(result);
        System.Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to not add the item to the list if it's already there then, try this:

Change

```
allPossibilities.Add(result);
```

To

```
if (!allPossibilities.Contains(result)) { allPossibilities.Add(result); }
```

Comment: That's a "hacky" solution, I was wondering where the mistake is in the actual "algorithm" if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I know it's a little bit too much, but it's structured and I use bitmask for putting dot between characters.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Do("qwerty");
}

public static void Do(string text)
{
    int i = 1;
    Text output = new Text();
    output.Add(new Dot(i));
    i = i * 2;
    foreach(char c in text)
    {
        output.Add(new textChar(c));
        output.Add(new Dot(i));
        i = i * 2;
    }

    int possibilites = output.Possibilites;
    for (i = 0; i < possibilites; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString(i));
    }

}

public class Text
{
    public List<character> characters = new List<character>();
    public void Add(character c)
    {
        characters.Add(c);
    }

    public int Possibilites
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, characters.Count(C => C is Dot)));
        }
    }

    public string ToString(int i)
    {
        string output = "";
        foreach (character c in characters)
        {
            if (c is textChar)
            {
                output += c.c;
            }
            else if (c is Dot)
            {
                if ((i & ((Dot)c).index) != 0)
                    output += c.c;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

}
public class character
{
    public char c { set; get; }
}
public class textChar : character
{
    public textChar(char c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class Dot : character
{
    public int index;
    public Dot(int i)
    {
        index = i;
        c = '.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which works.

Here the positions of the dots get saved as a matrix in the `binarycount` List as booleans. They define where the dots will be.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, printPossibilities("qwerty")));
}

private static List<string> printPossibilities(string str)
{
    List<string> allPossibilities = new List<string>();
    List<bool> binarycount = new List<bool>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i++) {
        binarycount.Add(false);
    }

    bool hasNext = true;
    while(hasNext)
    {
        string temp = str;
        for (int i = binarycount.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (binarycount[i])
                temp = temp.Insert(i+1, ".");
        }
        allPossibilities.Add(temp);
        hasNext = false;
        for (int i = binarycount.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (binarycount[i]) {
                binarycount[i] = false;
            } else {
                binarycount[i] = true;
                hasNext = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return allPossibilities;
}
```

output:

```
qwerty
qwert.y
qwer.ty
qwer.t.y
qwe.rty
qwe.rt.y
qwe.r.ty
qwe.r.t.y
qw.erty
qw.ert.y
qw.er.ty
qw.er.t.y
qw.e.rty
qw.e.rt.y
qw.e.r.ty
qw.e.r.t.y
q.werty
q.wert.y
q.wer.ty
q.wer.t.y
q.we.rty
q.we.rt.y
q.we.r.ty
q.we.r.t.y
q.w.erty
q.w.ert.y
q.w.er.ty
q.w.er.t.y
q.w.e.rty
q.w.e.rt.y
q.w.e.r.ty
q.w.e.r.t.y
```